# Rails as_json with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

In my application, `:foos` have many `:bars`, and I'm serializing each foo as JSON like so:

```
@foo.as_json(
  except: [:created_at, :updated_at], 
  include: { 
    bars: { only: [:ip_addr, :active] }
  }
)
```

This gives me the following:

```
{
  "id" => 2, 
  "name" => "Hello World",
  "bars" => [ 
    { "ip_addr" => "192.123.12.32", "active" => 0 }, 
    { "ip_addr" => "192.123.12.33", "active" => 1 } 
  ]
}
```

As you can see, my serialized hash includes an inactive bar. How can I exclude inactive bars from my hash?

It would be great if I could do this:

```
include: { bars: { only: { :active => true }}}
```

Have I taken `as_json` as far as it will go? Do I need to switch to active model serializers now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could try add some method like `active_bars` which will return exactly what you need like:

```
def active_bars
  bars.where active: true
end
```

or you could even add new relation:

```
has_many :active_bars, -> { where active: true }, class_name: '..', foreign_id: '..'
```

and then you will be able write:

```
@foo.as_json(
  except: [:created_at, :updated_at], 
  include: { 
    active_bars: { only: [:ip_addr, :active] }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you use as_json with conditions for customize json response for some actions, but model serializers  for default json response that you needed for the most responses.

Read these [Model_Serializer VS. as_json](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json), [record-serializers-from-scratch](http://matthewrobertson.org/blog/2013/08/06/active-record-serializers-from-scratch/).