# Exclude a specific object in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I need not to include a specific object in an array.

`Product` has many `line_items`:

Controller:

```
[...]

# example line_item Table
line_items = [
  {id: 1, name: "Static Name", ...},
  {id: 2, name: "Other name", ...}
]

@products = Product.order(created_at: :desc).where(domain: @shop.domain).as_json(
  include: {
    line_items: {
      only: [:quantiy, :unit_amount]
    }
  }
)

[...]
```

How not to include the hash that has a name of `Static Name`? That name will always name that. I need the other objects.

Comment: Not sure it's duplicate. I need to remove the entire object with a specific name inside it.

Comment: @Syler, you have to add new method/has_many relation say **non_static_items** in Product which will exclude line item with **Static Name**. Then you can  write **include: { non_static_items: {} }**. The same thing is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623971/rails-as-json-with-conditions

Comment: Got ya! Maybe a duplicate after all. Thanks for that