# Using scope in assoc. records JSON response - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, associations

Let's say I have a class called `Post` which `has_many :authors`, and `Author` has a number of associations I am including in my `#index` json response like so:

```
  post.as_json(
    include: [
      authors: {
        include: [:genre, :profile],
      },
    ],
  )
```

`Author` class has a scope called `active`. Is there a way to apply it inside the first `include: [...]`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623971/rails-as-json-with-conditions

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej the answer in that link is slightly different. It doesn't really provide a way to incorporate `scope`s but it does provide a nice workaround, so I am marking my question as a dupe